# Unable to set up Epson Bluetooth printer on 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, printing, scanner

I am trying to connect an Epson ET-2810 printer using bluetooth on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

My Bluetooth system detects the printer but I get the message "Not Set Up" so I cannot connect the printer.

I have no idea which drivers to download or how to install them. I may have already made a mess trying to install the wrong ones.

When I search for the printer in settings it is also detected there and has been added.

I have no idea with this OS, so please assume I know nothing. I am a beginner.

Comment: "*I may have made a mess already trying to install the wrong ones*" - Please elaborate with clear and complete details about what you've already done so far. If we need help you clean up a mess, we need to know what that is. FYI, this appears to be a fairly new printer, but you are running a 4+ year old operating system. Community support on 18.04 will end in roughly 8 months. Perhaps it's time to upgrade to a newer release?

Comment: I'd check what you're actually running, as 18.04.5 implies you're behind on security fixes & upgrades as this will show ([18.04.6 released](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) which refers to ISO release, installed systems upgraded before that date too).  If you apply all fixes/upgrades you situation may improve, or you may find you're already running 18.04.6 & not 18.04.5 as you state.

Comment: @ Nmath I installed some drivers for Linux of the Epson website. I chose random ones as I was uncertain which would be suitable.

Comment: @guiverc I have thought about this. I have had Ubuntu prompts often to upgrage to the newer versions but when I attempt to install them nothing happens (clicked the prompt but no response).  An upgrade could go a long way solving a few issues. I am hesitant because I have little idea what I am doing and worry I will lose files or crash everything. Is  safe and easy process?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly did you install and how exactly did you install them? We need to know exact details. We can't really work with ambiguous information that could mean practically anything.

Comment: I tend to use terminal to upgrade; ie. `sudo apt update` to update your software lists (ie. so your machine check what upgrades/package versions are available from the sources you system came with & any you've added... I tend to read this looking for anything that should be there; ie. 18.04 is *bionic* so non-bionic sources are a warning, as well as missing lines, or extra lines..) then if no issues `sudo apt full-upgrade` to install all upgrades available. I'd not expect issues unless they were made in prior session(s) & thus you'd created *minefields* with prior actions that can now explode.

Comment: Note the prior comment relates to commands that will only upgrade packages for your existing *bionic* or 18.04 release; unless you've polluted your sources with later releases earlier for example (why I tend to scan `apt update` output), as upgrading to a later/newer release uses different commands such as `do-release-upgrade` (`update-manager` etc) which do a lot more than just the `full-upgrade`

Comment: Thanks @guiverc. Potential minefield lol.  Should I just attempt to run the sudo apt full-upgrade through Terminal and hope I see you at the other end of it?

Comment: My prior comment lists what I use; ie. both `sudo apt update` is needed to make your system aware of what upgraded packages are available and the `sudo apt full-upgrade` command to apply those upgrades.  There are benefits to the two commands (ie. you're not wasting bandwidth & time re-updating software lists if all `apt` commands started with the `update`)

Comment: Thanks @guiverc. I have upgraded and connected the printer. Scanner not connecting now so looking into it.

Comment: Thanks @ Nmath I have upgraded and connected the printer. Scanner not connecting now so looking into it.